# Scraping multiple urls from same website multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping

I developed this program to scrape the name of each product, price, and shipping cost of each ps4 on a page on newegg.com. However, since there are multiple pages with ps4's on them how can I add multiple links to the source variable. Basically, I want to scrape multiple pages on newegg.com( ex: the ps4 page #1, #2, #4, etc).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

csv_file = open('newegg_scrape.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Product', 'Price', 'Shipping_info'])


for info in soup.find_all('div', class_='item-container'):
    prod = info.find('a', class_='item-title').text.strip()
    price = info.find('li', class_='price-current').text.strip().splitlines()[1].replace(u'\xa0', '')
    if  u'$' not in price:
        price = info.find('li', class_='price-current').text.strip().splitlines()[0].replace(u'\xa0', '')
    ship = info.find('li', class_='price-ship').text.strip()
    print(prod)
    print(price)
    print(ship)
    csv_writer.writerow([prod, price, ship])

   # print(price.splitlines()[1])
    print('-----------')
csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont do PHP but I have used Perl in the past to perform screen scraping.

If you notice down near the bottom of the page, there is a button bar for additional pages.  You will find the page 2 and additional urls to be of the format https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102/Page-2?PageSize=36&order=BESTMATCH

Simply make a loop to construct the URLs replace Page-2 with Page-3, 4 etc, query, scrape repeat.  I guess you just keep on going until you don't get a response or the page no longer has the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Grab the number of pages (from the first page scraped) based on its selector, then iterate over that while including the page number in the source.

## Explanation

1. Visit the first page `'https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102'`
2. Grab the items in the page (what your code does already)
3. Grab the number of pages from that page with its selector. Like this `soup.find('div', class_='list-tool-pagination').find('strong').text.split('/')[1]`
4. Return that number at the end
5. If it's more than 1, iterate over the rest of the pages. For each iteration the source becomes `'https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102/Page-' + page_number`

## Code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

base_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/PS4-Systems/SubCategory/ID-3102'

# Grab the number of pages
def get_pages_number(soup):
    pages_number = soup.find('div', class_='list-tool-pagination').find('strong').text.split('/')[1]
    return int(pages_number)

# Your code + dynamic URL + return number of pages
def scrape_page(page_number=1):
    # Make the source "dynamic" based on the page number
    source = requests.get(f'{base_url}/Page-{page_number}').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    # Soup processing goes here
    # You can use the code you posted to grab the price, etc...

    return get_pages_number(soup)

# Main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pages_number = scrape_page()

    # If there are more pages, we scrape them
    if pages_number > 1:
        for i in range(1, pages_number):
            scrape_page(i + 1)
```